# How to access SharePoint server 2013 or Office 365 from iOS application?

Tags: ios, objective-c, web-services, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-2013

I am new on share point web services implementation for ios. I read many forms and documentations and working with following code but not getting the expected output.

```
    -(IBAction)invokeService
    {
     NSMutableString* nodeContent = [[NSMutableString alloc]init];
     NSString* soapFormat = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",@"<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?><soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\" xmlns:soap=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\"><soap:Body><GetListItems xmlns=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/\"><listName>Product_List</listName><viewName>MyView</viewName><viewFields>Product_ID</viewFields><rowLimit>2</rowLimit><webID>6095B010-5500-48E5-B0B8-F828C49F6919</webID></GetListItems></soap:Body></soap:Envelope>"];

     NSURL *locationOfWebService = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://shophouse-public.sharepoint.com/vti_bin/lists.asmx"];
     NSMutableURLRequest *theRequest = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc]initWithURL:locationOfWebService];

        NSString *msgLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",[soapFormat length]];

        [theRequest addValue:@"text/xml; charset=utf-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
        [theRequest addValue:@"http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/GetListItems" forHTTPHeaderField:@"SOAPAction"];
        [theRequest addValue:msgLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
        [theRequest setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
        //the below encoding is used to send data over the net
        [theRequest setHTTPBody:[soapFormat dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

        NSURLConnection *connect = [[NSURLConnection alloc]initWithRequest:theRequest delegate:self];

        if (connect) {
            webData = [[NSMutableData alloc]init];
        } else {
            NSLog(@"No Connection established");
        }
    }


-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response
{
    [webData setLength:0];
}

-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data
{
    [webData appendData:data];
}

-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
{
    NSLog(@"ERROR with theConenction");
}

-(BOOL)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection canAuthenticateAgainstProtectionSpace:(NSURLProtectionSpace *)protectionSpace
{
    return YES;
}

-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveAuthenticationChallenge:(NSURLAuthenticationChallenge *)challenge
{
    NSURLCredential *credential = [NSURLCredential credentialWithUser:@"username@host.com" password:@"password" persistence:NSURLCredentialPersistenceForSession];

    [[challenge sender] useCredential:credential forAuthenticationChallenge:challenge];
}

-(void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
{
    NSLog(@"DONE. Received Bytes: %d", [webData length]);
    NSString *theXML = [[NSString alloc] initWithBytes: [webData mutableBytes] length:[webData length] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSLog(@"%@",theXML);

    convertToStringData = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:webData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    output.numberOfLines = 0;
    output.text = convertToStringData;
    [output sizeToFit];
}
```

**Response**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" lang="en-us" dir="ltr">
<head><meta name="GENERATOR" content="Microsoft SharePoint" /><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" /><meta http-equiv="Expires" content="0" /><meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8"/><meta name="ROBOTS" content="NOHTMLINDEX" /><title>

    Error

</title><link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/_layouts/15/1033/styles/corev15.css?rev=VXv2CYznLjo%2BTc5ut%2FR3Vg%3D%3D"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/_layouts/15/1033/styles/error.css?rev=qDbMvui05FpOZjrtNPXfnA%3D%3D"/>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.sharepointonline.com/7469/_layouts/15/init.js?rev=OwX5UBOr%2F67Bk%2FWTKhbWTw%3D%3D"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/ScriptResource.axd?d=9vAtsc182bLVrL7N93Pllbwp4H1D0ViWSsG6kkOE76JGm4UEnjwsh9oAiHbvzcSi4gCiM3KsJ7QB04_Ra73G_lGgU7f6najamg9WsPAXV3zqG6629IUS3AE5r92aV0qGoB2N_GcmGOxGnGzknc3SDujIz6-QULksx4yubbPPs3j1qV_OwWg9SW25pXrgBa6I0&amp;t=70998524"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/_layouts/15/blank.js?rev=pMPwHKfd1lfsB%2FzzBfItUA%3D%3D"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">RegisterSod("initstrings.js", "https:\u002f\u002fcdn.sharepointonline.com\u002f7469\u002f_layouts\u002f15\u002f1033\u002finitstrings.js?rev=hxd8ClaHhdv0iS7vbodfQg\u00253D\u00253D");</script>
<script type="text/javascript">RegisterSod("strings.js", "https:\u002f\u002fcdn.sharepointonline.com\u002f7469\u002f_layouts\u002f15\u002f1033\u002fstrings.js?rev=z\u00252BKlXmL7YWBU\u00252BXyxnDa0CA\u00253D\u00253D");RegisterSodDep("strings.js", "initstrings.js");</script>
<script type="text/javascript">RegisterSod("sp.res.resx", "\u002f_layouts\u002f15\u002fScriptResx.ashx?culture=en\u00252Dus\u0026name=SP\u00252ERes\u0026rev=fjveXx5bAqWBwO9EAD2fbg\u00253D\u00253D");</script>
<script type="text/javascript">RegisterSod("sp.runtime.js", "https:\u002f\u002fcdn.sharepointonline.com\u002f7469\u002f_layouts\u002f15\u002fsp.runtime.js?rev=1P\u00252FniNmkBoNDZ\u00252BXB28xr3w\u00253D\u00253D");RegisterSodDep("sp.runtime.js", "sp.res.resx");</script>
<script type="text/javascript">RegisterSod("sp.js", "https:\u002f\u002fcdn.sharepointonline.com\u002f7469\u002f_layouts\u002f15\u002fsp.js?rev=70O02GNOlBVieGkpXF1EpQ\u00253D\u00253D");RegisterSodDep("sp.js", "sp.runtime.js");RegisterSodDep("sp.js", "sp.ui.dialog.js");RegisterSodDep("sp.js", "sp.res.resx");</script>
<script type="text/javascript">RegisterSod("sp.init.js", "https:\u002f\u002fcdn.sharepointonline.com\u002f7469\u002f_layouts\u002f15\u002fsp.init.js?rev=XVk7voUwNi13Sa\u00252Bkh6Oebw\u00253D\u00253D");</script>
<script type="text/javascript">RegisterSod("sp.ui.dialog.js", "https:\u002f\u002fcdn.sharepointonline.com\u002f7469\u002f_layouts\u002f15\u002fsp.ui.dialog.js?rev=f8M8W644Osnu\u00252BN4d9cy\u00252FnA\u00253D\u00253D");RegisterSodDep("sp.ui.dialog.js", "sp.init.js");RegisterSodDep("sp.ui.dialog.js", "sp.res.resx");</script>
<script type="text/javascript">RegisterSod("core.js", "https:\u002f\u002fcdn.sharepointonline.com\u002f7469\u002f_layouts\u002f15\u002fcore.js?rev=zYH3XZtfQ1RoDYlZ6QWWRQ\u00253D\u00253D");RegisterSodDep("core.js", "strings.js");</script>
<script type="text/javascript">RegisterSod("foldhyperlink.js", "https:\u002f\u002fcdn.sharepointonline.com\u002f7469\u002f_layouts\u002f15\u002ffoldhyperlink.js?rev=d8wlsDRRn9Fmi4FiVf0FZw\u00253D\u00253D");</script>

    <meta name="Robots" content="NOINDEX " />
    <meta name="SharePointError" content="0" />
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="/_layouts/15/images/favicon.ico?rev=31" type="image/vnd.microsoft.icon" /></head>
<body id="ms-error-body" onload="if (typeof(_spBodyOnLoadWrapper) != 'undefined') _spBodyOnLoadWrapper();">
    <form method="post" action="../_layouts/15/error.aspx" id="aspnetForm" onsubmit="if (typeof(_spFormOnSubmitWrapper) != &#39;undefined&#39;) {return _spFormOnSubmitWrapper();} else {return true;}">
<input type="hidden" name="__VIEWSTATE" id="__VIEWSTATE" value="/wEPDwUKLTIzOTk3ODA3OA9kFgJmD2QWAgIBD2QWAgIDD2QWAgIJD2QWAgIBD2QWBAIDDw8WAh4HVmlzaWJsZWhkZAIHD2QWAgIBDw8WAh4XTGlua1RpdGxlV2hlbkZvbGRDbG9zZWQFEVRlY2huaWNhbCBEZXRhaWxzZBYIZg9kFgICAQ8PZBYCHgdvbmNsaWNrBcgBRW5zdXJlU2NyaXB0UGFyYW1zKCdmb2xkaHlwZXJsaW5rLmpzJywgJ1RvZ2dsZUZvbGRUZXh0JywgJ2FkYzVmY2U5NGQ2YzRmZmM5NjkwMGYxOTFlMzNkYWFkJywgJ2N0bDAwX1BsYWNlSG9sZGVyTWFpbl9Gb2xkTGlua19fbW9yZURldGFpbHNMaW5rJywgJ1RlY2huaWNhbCBEZXRhaWxzJywgJ1RlY2huaWNhbCBEZXRhaWxzJyk7O3JldHVybiBmYWxzZTsWAgIBDw8WAh4EVGV4dAURVGVjaG5pY2FsIERldGFpbHMWBB4EaHJlZgUBIx8CBRtQcmV2ZW50RGVmYXVsdE5hdmlnYXRpb24oKTtkAgUPDxYCHwBoZGQCCQ8PFgIfAwU0Q29ycmVsYXRpb24gSUQ6IDU5YTI1YTljLTRjYjEtOTA3ZS02OTgwLTNmYjRkODM3ZGRkNmRkAgsPDxYCHwMFJERhdGUgYW5kIFRpbWU6IDExLzI2LzIwMTMgOToxMjoxMSBQTWRkZHPzIaFXIi/Q7jAQC0nRRGIvvWfPs5kpM6w57DHdiRe3" />


<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
var g_presenceEnabled = true;
var g_wsaEnabled = true;
var g_correlationId = '59a25a9c-4cb1-907e-6980-3fb4d837ddd6';
var g_wsaQoSEnabled = false;
var g_wsaQoSDataPoints = [];
var g_wsaRUMEnabled = true;var g_wsaLCID = 1033;
var g_wsaListTemplateId = null;
var _fV4UI=true;var _spPageContextInfo = {webServerRelativeUrl: "\u002f", webAbsoluteUrl: "https:\u002f\u002fshophouse-public.sharepoint.com", siteAbsoluteUrl: "https:\u002f\u002fshophouse-public.sharepoint.com", serverRequestPath: "\u002fvti_bin\u002flists.asmx", layoutsUrl: "_layouts\u002f15", webTitle: "", webTemplate: "", tenantAppVersion: "none", webLogoUrl: "\u002fSiteAssets\u002flogo.png", webLanguage: 1033, currentLanguage: 1033, currentUICultureName: "en-US", currentCultureName: "en-US", clientServerTimeDelta: new Date("2013-11-27T05:12:11.8586055Z") - new Date(), siteClientTag: "237$$16.0.2308.1210", crossDomainPhotosEnabled:true, webUIVersion:15, webPermMasks:{High:0,Low:0}, pagePersonalizationScope:1, alertsEnabled:true, siteServerRelativeUrl: "\u002f", allowSilverlightPrompt:'True',"themedCssFolderUrl" : "/_catalogs/theme/Themed/1885E09D","themedImageFileNames" : {"spcommon.png" : "spcommon-B35BB0A9.themedpng?ctag=3","ellipsis.11x11x32.png" : "ellipsis.11x11x32-2F01F47D.themedpng?ctag=3","O365BrandSuite.95x30x32.png" : "O365BrandSuite.95x30x32-C212E2FD.themedpng?ctag=3","socialcommon.png" : "socialcommon-6F3394A9.themedpng?ctag=3","spnav.png" : "spnav-230C537D.themedpng?ctag=3"}};//]]>
</script>

<script src="/_layouts/15/blank.js?rev=pMPwHKfd1lfsB%2FzzBfItUA%3D%3D" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
if (typeof(DeferWebFormInitCallback) == 'function') DeferWebFormInitCallback();Flighting.ExpFeatures = [1076891650,0];//]]>
</script>


    <div id="ms-error-header" class="ms-pr">
        <h1 class="ms-core-pageTitle">

    <div id="ctl00_PlaceHolderPageTitleInTitleArea_ErrorPageTitlePanel">

    Sorry, something went wrong
</div>

        </h1>
        <div>

        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="ms-error">
        <div id="ms-error-top">

        </div>
        <div id="ms-error-content">
            <div id="ms-error-error-content">
                <div id="DeltaPlaceHolderMain">




    <div>
        <span id="ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_LabelMessage">The file you are attempting to save or retrieve has been blocked from this Web site by the server administrators.</span>
    </div>
    <div id="ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_FoldPanel" class="ms-error-detailsFold">

        <div id="ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_FoldLink_foldLinkWrapper">

    <div id="ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_FoldLink_foldLinkPanel" class="ms-foldHyperLink-panel" onclick="EnsureScriptParams(&#39;foldhyperlink.js&#39;, &#39;ToggleFoldText&#39;, &#39;adc5fce94d6c4ffc96900f191e33daad&#39;, &#39;ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_FoldLink__moreDetailsLink&#39;, &#39;Technical Details&#39;, &#39;Technical Details&#39;);;return false;">

        <a id="ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_FoldLink__moreDetailsLink" class="ms-commandLink ms-floatLeft" href="#" onclick="PreventDefaultNavigation();">Technical Details</a>
        <div class="ms-clear"></div>

            </div>

        </div><div class="ms-hide" id="adc5fce94d6c4ffc96900f191e33daad">

            <div>
                <p>
                    <span class="ms-descriptiontext">

                    </span>
                </p>
                <p>
                    <span class="ms-descriptiontext">

                        <div id="ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_FoldLink_WSSEndUser_troubleshootingPanel">

                            <span id="ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_FoldLink_helptopic_WSSEndUser_troubleshooting"><a title="Troubleshoot issues with Microsoft SharePoint Foundation. - Opens in new window" href="javascript:HelpWindowKey('WSSEndUser_troubleshooting')">Troubleshoot issues with Microsoft SharePoint Foundation.</a></span>

        </div>
                    </span>
                </p>
                <p>
                    <span id="ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_FoldLink_RequestGuidText" class="ms-metadata">Correlation ID: 59a25a9c-4cb1-907e-6980-3fb4d837ddd6</span>
                </p>
                <p>
                    <span id="ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_FoldLink_DateTimeText" class="ms-metadata">Date and Time: 11/26/2013 9:12:11 PM</span>
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
    <div class="ms-error-techMsg">
        <hr />
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">// <![CDATA[ 


        var gearPage = document.getElementById('ms-loading-box');
        if(null != gearPage)
        {
            gearPage.parentNode.removeChild(gearPage);
            document.title = "Error";
        }
        function _spBodyOnLoad()
        {
            var intialFocus = (document.getElementById("ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_FoldLink__moreDetailsLink"));
            try
            {
                intialFocus.focus();
            }
            catch(ex)
            {
            }
        }
    // ]]>
</script>


</div>
            </div>

                <div id="ms-error-gobackcont" class="ms-calloutLink">
                    <a href="/" class='ms-calloutLink' id="ctl00_PlaceHolderGoBackLink_idSimpleGoBackToHome">Go back to site</a>
                </div>

        </div>
    </div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

**Details**

Now I am getting stuck with this code and don't know what to do further. I read from some post that, this code can work for share point 2010 servers but it will not work for share point 2013 because In sharepoint 2013 the server uses claim based authentication and which can achieve by manage cookies in client app.

Can anyone help me to sort out from this problem ? What is the proper flow of authentication method for client apps to access share point 2013 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is good third party open source library for the making Rest Requests to the SharePoint online (part of office 365)

Please go to below link:
https://github.com/jimmywim/SPRestAPI (No longer maintained)

https://github.com/jimmywim/SPMobile

Comment: Yeah!! Its working fine. Very helpful library for IOS platform to communicate with share point 2013 server.

Comment: @Thomas Johannesmeyer Thanks very much.